# QUERY function works in example sheet but not in a new sheet with same formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

[image: Screenshot from new sheet]

[image: screen shot from google example sheet]

I get error when using the formula in a new sheet, but the same formula works in google`s example sheet.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It could be an issue with the Google sheet Language setting. This might guide you -  [Try this](https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/using-formulas-in-different-languages-in-google-sheets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sheets are of different locale - English / Non-English

English sheets use `,` while in Non-English you need to use `;`

therefore:

```
=QUERY(A1:B5; "select B"; 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right, it was of different locale :P 3 Hours wasted. Damn. (Norway btw)